# java unit test mock HttpClient and webdav

Tags: java, unit-testing, httpclient, webdav, easymock

Hello I have a class for doing webdav related operations such as creating a directory, Implementatiion can be seen below (the createDir method). The question is how to test it nicely, perhaps using EasyMock or a similar lib. Any ideas? thanks!

```
package foobar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.DeleteMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PutMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity;

import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.DavMethod;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.MkColMethod;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import mypackage.httpdclient.util.URLHandler;


public class WebDavImpl{

    private static final String SEPARATOR = " ----- ";
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    public StorageSpaceClientImpl() {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public String createDir(String dirName) {

        String response = null;
        String url = URLHandler.getInstance().getDirectoryUrl(dirName);
        DavMethod mkcol = new MkColMethod(url);
        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(mkcol);
            response = mkcol.getStatusCode() + SEPARATOR + mkcol.getStatusText();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } finally {
            mkcol.releaseConnection();
        }

        return response;
    }

   }
```

Comment: the catch statement that does nothing is only pain and death.  You should do something there or let the exception bubble up.

Comment: Did you found a solution to create webdav relateded tests?